# Unity how to pause the game by just pressing whitespace once using input system? help me plz

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I followed a video and tried to complete the pause game function in my game.But when I started playing the game, I found that I can only pause the game by keep pressing the whtespace.My ideal solution is to pause the game by just press the key once. The follwing code is my scripts and thank you a lot in advance

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using Unity.VisualScripting;
 using UnityEngine; 
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 
 public class PauseManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public float timeLeft = 0;
     public bool timeOn = false;
     public Text timeText;
     public static bool pause = false;
     public PauseActionInput _pauseAction;
     public AudioSource audiosource1;
     public GameObject pausemenu;
 
     
     public void Start()
     {
         
         _pauseAction.PauseActionMap.pause.performed += _ => determine_pause();
         
 
     }
 
     public void Awake()
     {
         _pauseAction = new PauseActionInput();
        
 
 
 
     }
 
     public void Update()
     {
         if (PauseManager.pause) return;
         
 
 
     }
 
     private void OnEnable()
     {
         _pauseAction.Enable();
     }
 
     private void OnDisable()
     {
         _pauseAction.Disable();
     }
 
     public void determine_pause()
     {
         if (pause)
         {
             resumeGame();
         }
         else
         {
             pauseGame();
         }
     }
 
     public void resumeGame()
     {
         Time.timeScale = 1;
         AudioListener.pause = false;
         pausemenu.SetActive(false);
         pause = false;
         Debug.Log("game is resume");
     }
 
     public void pauseGame()
     {
         Time.timeScale = 0;
         AudioListener.pause = true;
         pausemenu.SetActive(true);
         pause = true;
         Debug.Log("game is stopped");
     }
 
  
     
 }
```

My ideal solution is to pause the game by just press the key once.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the `Action Type` must be on the **`Button`**, because in `Pass Through`, the callback works round-trip.

[image: Button]

In the second step, remove the complexity of the additional methods and run an off and on pedal in the method as below, and the problem will be solved.

```cs
public void Start()
{
    _pauseAction = new PauseActionInput();
    _pauseAction.Enable();
    _pauseAction.PauseActionMap.pause.performed += _ => TurnStop(!pause);
}

private void TurnStop(bool _turn)
{
    pause = _turn;

    if (pause) 
    {
        // In Stop..
    }
    else
    {
        // In Resume..
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote what u told, but nothing happened, after writing "Onenable" and "Ondisable"methods, it is back to the situation that I mentoined before. Could u plz tell me more about the"Onenable"functions?

Comment: @tobyteng onEnable works when your object becomes active. You don't need those two at all. As I answered in the update, take everyone to start because it may not work in awake.

Comment: It doesn't work.....situation remains the same

Comment: in the input system settings, the Update Mode is"process events in dynamic update"

Comment: and the Play Mode Input Behavior is"Keyboard and pointer respect  gameview focus"

Comment: @tobyteng Put a picture of the input action and make sure that no other object has this code.